# Building Contiki Application to Arduino Uno

Tags: ubuntu, arduino-uno, contiki

So I just started using contiki (I have downloaded the Arduino version) and can't figure out how to upload a program to a board. Basically, this is how far I've got:

```
make TARGET=Arduino ARDUNIO_MODEL=Uno
```

Which gives me and executable:

```
hello-world.arduino
```

After this, I really have no idea what to do.